# Performance issue with select query in Firebird

Tags: sql, database, performance, optimization, firebird2.5

I have two tables, one small (~ 400 rows), one large (~ 15 million rows), and I am trying to find the records from the small table that don't have an associated entry in the large table.

I am encountering ***massive performance issues*** with the query.

The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM small_table WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT NULL FROM large_table WHERE large_table.small_id = small_table.id)
```

The column `large_table.small_id` references small_table's `id` field, which is its primary key.
The query plan shows that the foreign key index is used for the large_table:

```
PLAN (large_table (RDB$FOREIGN70))
PLAN (small_table NATURAL)
```

Statistics have been recalculated for indexes on both tables.

The query takes several hours to run. Is this expected?

- If so, can I rewrite the query so that it will be faster?
- If not, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Firebird, but in other DBs often a join is faster.

```
SELECT    *
FROM      small_table st
LEFT JOIN large_table lt
ON        st.id = lt.small_id
WHERE     lt.small_id IS NULL
```

Maybe give that a try?

Another option, if you're really stuck, and depending on the situation this needs to be run in, is to take the small_id column out of the large_table, possibly into a temp table, and then do a left join / EXISTS query.

Answer (score 1):

If the large table only has relatively few distinct values for small_id, the following might perform better:

```
select *
from small_table st left outer join
     (select distinct small_id
      from large_table
     ) lt
     on lt.small_id = st.id
where lt.small_id is null
```

In this case, the performance would be better by doing a full scan of the large table and then index lookups in the small table -- the opposite of what it is doing.  Doing a distinct could do just an index scan on the large table which then uses the primary key index on the small table.